# I am attempting to use Appium to run some automated tests on a hybrid mobile device built using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, appium

I am currently trying to do a POC to automate application build using Phonegap framework . I am trying to automate phonegap application for the first time. Can anyone please help me in this .

From where can I get sample application to start the automation.
Sample code snippet to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

- Check this out: https://github.com/appium/java-client
- and this is for examples of tests in a variety of different languages: https://github.com/appium/sample-code
- this is for automating hybrid apps: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md

Comment: Hi ,I am able to successfully automate one scenario using Appium for iOS application .But when I tried to do the same for Android application I am facing issues while capturing element locators . Appium Inspector is able to detect only up to the Web view. However I am able to do the same doe ioS successfully. Could you please help me .How can we capture locators of elements for Android PhoneGap application using Appium.

Answer (score 1):

To inspect elements on Android use chrome inspect tools, by opening a new chrome browser and type

> chrome://inspect

into URL box. This should list devices attached to machine and webview must be available. Click on Inspect link to view properties for all elements in application screen.

Thanks,
Sujata